# How can I exchange rows for multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dictionary where each value contains a number of different DataFrame that is grouped by `Name`, but I'd like to make it so that instead they are grouped by `Time`. I'm trying to apply a group-by/apply/split type function, but because they are not a single DataFrame (but rather split DataFrames in a dictionary), I'm a bit stuck.

Toy example of a dictionary with 2 dataframes:

```
{'df1':    Name  Time
 0  Greg  1-10
 1  Greg  5-10
 'df2':     Name  Time
 0   Jeff  5-10
 1  Jeff  1-10}
```

To reproduce:

```
d = {'df1': pd.DataFrame({'Name': ["Jeff", "Greg"], 'Times': ["1-5", "5-10"]}), 'df2': pd.DataFrame({'Name': ["Jeff", "Greg"], 'Times': ["5-10", "1-5"]})}
```

Desired output:

```
{'df1':    Name  Time
 0  Greg  1-10
 1  Jeff  1-10
 'df2':     Name  Time
 0  Jeff  5-10
 1  Greg  5-10}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, your data looks like below (let's call it `data`):

```
{'df1':    Name.  Time
 0  Greg.  1-10
 1  Greg.  5-10,
 'df2':     Name  Time
 0   Jeff  5-10
 1  Jeff.  1-10}
```

Here's one option: `concat` + `groupby` "Time" + dict comprehension:

```
out = {f'df{i}': df for i, (_, df) in 
       enumerate(pd.concat((data['df1'].rename(columns={'Name.':'Name'}), 
                            data['df2'])).groupby('Time'), 1)}
```

Output:

```
{'df1':     Name  Time
 0  Greg.  1-10
 1  Jeff.  1-10,
 'df2':     Name  Time
 1  Greg.  5-10
 0   Jeff  5-10}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, enke. Would a similar method work with a dictionary of n entries?

Comment: @DougieFresh if your goal is the same, the number of values shouldn’t matter. Just make sure the column names are the same. For example, in your sample, “Name” columns weren’t the same, so I had to manually change it; otherwise you could concatenate with a simple `pd.concat(data.values())`

Comment: @DougieFresh `pd.concat(d.values())` simply concatenates all DataFrames stored in `d` and creates a single DataFrame. We `groupby` "Time" on that DataFrame and iterate over each group to create separate DataFrames. `enumerate` is only used to assign key names to the output dictionary (using f-strings); it's not really essential; if a list suffices, you could use `[df for _, df in pd.concat(d.values()).groupby('Time')]` instead.